# Secure date storaging (date hashing)

Tags: security, hash, cryptography

I am looking for an algorithm that allows to save a date (any format is okey) in a secure way and check if this date is newer or older than another. I do not need reverse the date,so once the date is saved in secure format it will never be converted into plain format.

Expectation:
date written as e.g. D='2014-03-28' (can be number, string, whatever)

f(d) <-- magical function I am asking about

f(D) = 98abc58eda82 (magical hash)

now, I have another date

DD = '2014-05-14'
f(DD) = 83h56fab5b8e (another hash)

and there exist comparator that allows this:

f(D)  > f(DD) gives false
f(DD) > f(D)  gives true

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you hash the date anyway?

Comment: Cause I'd love to know user tried to change the date to extend validity of licence. I cannot use NTP, cause on most of machines there will not be connection to network.

Comment: You can't do it securely, only obscurely.

Comment: What would prevent a "replay attack"? The user could simply copy the date hash from another license. Also, if he doesn't have another license available, he could simply reverse engineer the program to find out how the hash is calculated.